# Space of equivariant homomorphism from the space of G-linear maps to a vector space

Tags: representation-theory, equivariant-maps, irreducible-representation

Let $(V, \rho)$ be a representation of a finite group $G$ whose irreducible representations over complex numbers are $(W_i, \pi_i)$ for $1 \le i \le m$. Let $$H_i=\text{Hom}_G(W_i,V)= \{\tau \in \text{Hom}(W_i,V) \mid \tau \pi_i(g)=\rho(g) \tau\ \ \ \ \forall g \in G\}.$$

Question: What are the rank and range of elements of $\text{Hom}_G(H_i,V)$?

What is the dimension of $\text{Hom}_G(H_i,V)$?

### Motivation

Let $d_i=\dim(H_i)$ and $n_i=\dim(W_i)$. From representation theory, we know  $V \cong V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_m$, where $V_i=W_i^{\oplus d_i}$. That is, $V$ can be identified by the direct sum of $m$ subspaces each of which is a $d_i$ copy of $W_i$.

Moreover, each $V_i \cong H_i^{\oplus n_i}$. That is, each $V_i$ is isomorphic to a $n_i$ copy of the subspace of $G$-linear map from $W_i$ to $V$.

---

Added later:

We can see this if we let G act on $H_i \otimes W_i$ through the tensor product of the trivial representation of G on $H_i$ and the given representation on $W_i$, then $\sum h \otimes w \mapsto \sum h(w)$ defines an isomorphism from $H_i \otimes W_i$ onto $V_i$. Now, if we choose a basis for $W_i$, then $V_i \cong H_i \otimes \mathbb{C}^{n_i}$.

---

So,
$$\text{Hom}_G(V,V) \cong \text{Hom}_G( \bigoplus_{i=1}^m V_i,V) \cong  \bigoplus_{i=1}^m \text{Hom}_G(V_i,V),$$
where $$\text{Hom}_G(V_i,V) \cong \text{Hom}_G(H_i^{\oplus n_i},V) \cong \text{Hom}_G(H_i,V)^{\oplus n_i}.$$

That is why I would like to know more about $\text{Hom}_G(H_i,V)$ and its elements.

Since $$\text{Hom}_G(V_i,V) \cong \text{Hom}_G(W_i,V)^{\oplus d_i} \cong \text{Hom}_G(H_i,V)^{\oplus n_i},$$ I suspesct $n_i \dim(\text{Hom}_G(H_i,V))= d_i^2$. But, this does not make sense since what if $n_i \nmid d_i^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct calculation. We have

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \text{Hom}_G(W_i, V) &\cong& \text{Hom}_G(W_i, \bigoplus_j W_j^{d_j}) \\
 &\cong& \bigoplus_j \text{Hom}_G(W_i, W_j^{d_j}) \\
 &\cong& \text{Hom}_G(W_i, W_i)^{d_i} \\
 &\cong& \mathbb{C}^{d_i} \end{eqnarray*}$$

by the universal property of the direct sum, then Schur's lemma. This tells us that a homomorphism $W_i \to V$ must land in the $W_i$-isotypic component $W_i^{d_i}$, and since by Schur's lemma it must be either zero or injective, its rank is either zero or $\dim W_i$, and its range is either zero or some invariant subspace of $W_i^{d_i}$ isomorphic to $W_i$.

$\text{Hom}_G(W_i, V)$ calculates the "multiplicity space" of the irreducible representation $W_i$ in $V$, which is an invariant version of the multiplicity.

Similarly we have

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \text{End}_G(V) &\cong& \text{Hom}_G(\bigoplus_i W_i^{d_i}, \bigoplus_j W_j^{d_j}) \\ 
 &\cong& \bigoplus_{i, j} \text{Hom}_G(W_i^{d_i}, W_j^{d_j}) \\ 
 &\cong& \bigoplus_i \text{End}_G(W_i^{d_i}) \\
 &\cong& \bigoplus_i M_{d_i}(\mathbb{C}) \end{eqnarray*}$$

again by the universal property of the direct sum, then Schur's lemma.

Comment: $\dim(V_i)=\dim(W_i^{d_i})=d_i \dim(W_i)=d_in_i$. Also, $\dim(H_i^{n_i})=n_i \dim(H_i)=n_id_i$. So, dimensions work. Reference for why $H_i^{n_i} \cong V_i$: Serre, Ex. 2.8. It says that $V_i \cong H_i \otimes W_i$, so if we choose a basis for $W_i$, then we have the result. What do you think? Is there any problem with my understanding?

Comment: @khashayar: ah, okay, I misread $V_i$ for $W_i$. This is a strange way to say it, it's much clearer to say $V_i \cong H_i \otimes W_i$ since this is even an isomorphism of representations.

Comment: So is Hom$_G(V_i,V) \cong$ Hom$_G(H_i,V)^{n_i}$ valid?

Comment: @khashayar: $H_i$ is not a representation of $G$, so the RHS doesn't make sense.

Comment: Every $G$-stable subspace of a representation is a sub representation. $H_i$ is a $G$-stable subspace of the representation Hom$(W_i,V)$. For $\phi \in$Hom$(W_i,V)$, $(g\phi)(w)=\rho(g)(\phi(\pi_i(g^{-1})w))$. Is that right?

Comment: @khashayar: as a subrepresentation of $\text{Hom}(W_i, V)$, $H_i$ carries the trivial representation. So $\text{Hom}_G(H_i, V)$ only detects the trivial part of $V$. If we suppose this is given by $V_1 = W_1^{d_1}$ then it's $\text{Hom}(H_i, W_1)^{d_1}$ which has dimension $d_i d_1$. On the other hand $\text{Hom}_G(V_i, V) \cong \text{Hom}_G(W_i^{d_i}, W_i^{d_i})$ has dimension $d_i^2$, by Schur's lemma. I cannot understand what you're trying to do and I don't know why you edited the question.

Comment: Do you mean $\text{Hom}_G(H_i, W_1)^{d_1}$ by $\text{Hom}(H_i, W_1)^{d_1}$? If yes, why $\dim(\text{Hom}_G(H_i, W_1))=d_i$?

Comment: No, I mean Hom, these are vector spaces, they don't carry nontrivial $G$-actions. $W_1$ is just the $1$-dimensional trivial representation so $\text{Hom}(H_i, W_1)$ is just the dual $H_i^{\ast}$ and it has the same dimension as $H_i$. Again, I don't understand what you're trying to do. Your notation is also, IMO, making this all a lot harder than it should be, since it doesn't distinguish $G$-representations from plain vector spaces and the dimension notations don't match the vector space notations.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I want to show there exists a basis $B$ which is called symmetry-adapted basis such that, for every $\tau \in \text{End}_G(V)$, $[\tau]_B= \bigoplus_{i=1}^m I_{n_i} \otimes A_i$ for some $d_i \times d_i$ matrices $A_i$. So I tried to decompose End$_G(V_i)$ to show matrices in this subspace can be written as a direct sum of $n_i$ copy of a $d_i \times d_i$ matrix. Do you think I need to creat another question?

Comment: Yes, just ask the question you actually want to know the answer to. $\text{End}_G(V_i) \cong M_{d_i}(\mathbb{C})$ by repeated application of Schur's lemma.